# Modifying a toggleable menu

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I have a login menu, that when you hit the element "log-in" it will drop down a loggin menu. The thing is that I can't move the log in box to the left.

The reason I want to do this is when the users use a smaller screen half of the box won't show up properly.

===============================================================

**Sample code below:**

```css
#login-dp{
        min-width: 250px;
        padding: 14px 14px 0;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    }
    #login-dp .help-block{
        font-size:12px    
    }
    #login-dp .bottom{
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
        border-top:1px solid #ddd;
        clear:both;
        padding:14px;
    }
    #login-dp .social-buttons{
        margin:12px 0    
    }
    #login-dp .social-buttons a{
        width: 49%;
    }
    #login-dp .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .btn-fb{
        color: #fff;
        background-color:#3b5998;
    }
    .btn-fb:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background-color:#496ebc 
    }
    .btn-tw{
        color: #fff;
        background-color:#55acee;
    }
    .btn-tw:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background-color:#59b5fa;
    }
    @media(max-width:768px){
        #login-dp{
            background-color: inherit;
            color: #fff;
        }
        #login-dp .bottom{
            background-color: inherit;
            border-top:0 none;
        }
    }
```

```html
 <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                             <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        Login via
                                        <div class="social-buttons">
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
                                        </div>
                                        or
                                         <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                     <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                                                     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                     <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                                                     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                                                     <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Forget the password ?</a></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                     <label>
                                                     <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
                                                     </label>
                                                </div>
                                         </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom text-center">
                                        New here ? <a href="#"><b>Join Us</b></a>
                                    </div>
                             </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
```

Comment: Please provide the preview or codes that you have done, without those it is very hard to tell what's wrong with your site.

Comment: Ok I posted the code

Comment: Your code is incomplete so I cant tell much from it, in your case try adding `text-align:left;` or `float:right;` to your log-in element.